# Postgres: with identity column as unique key, need help in upsert

Tags: postgresql, identity, upsert

Follow the below script to create two tables source_t and dest_t.

```
drop table if exists source_t;

create table source_t as
(select 1 id, 'dummy1' varcol union
select 3,'dummy3');

drop table if exists dest_t;

create table dest_t as
(select 1 id, 'mmy' varcol
union select 2,'dummy2');

ALTER TABLE dest_t 
    ALTER id SET NOT NULL,  
    ALTER id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS identity;

   ALTER TABLE dest_t ADD CONSTRAINT UNQ_CON_dest_t unique  (id);
```

Now the content of two tables:

source_t:

[image]

dest_t:

[image]

1st case  is when I want to update a record using upsert:
Now my upsert statement:

```
insert into    dest_t 
select * from source_t
on conflict on constraint unq_con_dest_t 
do update set (varcol)=( select excluded.varcol);
```

The expectation is to just update varcol column for id = 1 in the dest_t table.

The error I am getting :

> ERROR: cannot insert into column "id"
> Detail: Column "id" is an identity column defined as GENERATED ALWAYS.

First question: Why am I getting insert error while the select query is returning only data which is the "updateable" candidate.

OK. Now I change my upsert as below to see if it gets fixed:

```
insert into    dest_t OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE
select * from source_t
on conflict on constraint unq_con_dest_t 
do update set (varcol)=( select excluded.varcol);
```

And even though this is not a fix, let's say I was able to proceed with the expected update.

2nd case:

let's insert a record in source_t as below, since this does not exist in dest_t this can be a "insert" candidate for dest_t :

```
insert into source_t values(null,'dummy0');
```

Running same upsert statement:

```
insert into    dest_t OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE
select * from source_t
on conflict on constraint unq_con_dest_t 
do update set (varcol)=( select excluded.varcol);
```

Now I get the below error:

> ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

Yes, I understand it cannot insert null to not null column. I get the same error with or without using the "overriding" clause.

Second question: How do I make sure the upsert query automatically increments identity column when it is inserting and while updating it uses the existing value returned in select query of upsert. And identity column is the unique key.

Or is it not possible to use "UPSERT" when the unique key of the destination table is the "identity" column.?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `set (varcol)=( select excluded.varcol);` can be simplified to `set varcol =  excluded.varcol`

Comment: It seems strange to me that you need to compare a _generated_ value for the conflict detection. I would have assumed the varcol columns decides if it's a duplicate or not.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, There is a reason I added "select" there. When a table has only two columns with one as a unique key, then it does not allow you to just update one column using upsert. Strange but you can test as well. Use same script as above.
ERROR : ERROR: source for a multiple-column UPDATE item must be a sub-SELECT or ROW() expression

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, in my case varcol column can have duplicate values.
By the way, thank you for editing and formatting the question.

Comment: No, you don't need the SELECT: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=11495ed66c8ef82405eb7d764c1182d8  - but using a generated value as the conflict resolution still seems like a really strange thing to do. As you have no real control over the generated values, how do you know that ID=1 in one table should **really** match ID=1 in the other? What if rows were deleted or an INSERT was rolled back? Then you'd have gaps in the numbers and the whole "matching on ID" doesn't work any longer.

Comment: You are right considering example I gave. But actually in my real scenario, source and destination will be same table.

Comment: Then why didn't you show that in your question? But to be honest: in that case this makes even less sense to me.

Comment: And with two different tables, it would make sense too.
What if I have two tables with employee details and all similar columns. One gets updated from some process and another just keeps subset of records based on a condition. And we want to keep the IDs in both tables common.tables might have other uncommon columns as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133919/discussion-between-sajith-p-shetty-and-a-horse-with-no-name).